# How to display array objects from getJson with condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I want to get array object result with a condition (in my case, i want only get data if administrative area level 2). how can i do this? i have try on case below, but sometimes a i get a blank alert. maybe i must create a looping and inside them create condition ? any help would be appreciated. :)

here is json result :

```
{
 "results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "77379",
           "short_name" : "77379",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Spring",
           "short_name" : "Spring",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Harris County",
           "short_name" : "Harris County",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Texas",
           "short_name" : "TX",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Spring, TX 77379, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 30.088189,
              "lng" : -95.47364999999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 29.9871611,
              "lng" : -95.5887879
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 30.0314279,
           "lng" : -95.5302337
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 30.088189,
              "lng" : -95.47364999999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 29.9871611,
              "lng" : -95.5887879
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJtZcGtDLNQIYRtGE9AgmSOPQ",
     "postcode_localities" : [ "Klein", "Spring" ],
     "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
    }
  ],
  "status" : "OK"
  }
```

Here is my code :

```
var latLng = marker.latLng;
$latitude.value = latLng.lat();
$longitude.value = latLng.lng();
var urlgeocode = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + 
latLng.lat()+ "," +latLng.lng() + "&key=AIzaSyB0Yef9tL8vM148wqdMTmYMBEO7qjPtKXE";

$.getJSON(urlgeocode, function(data, textStatus){
var streetadress= data.results[0].address_components[2].long_name;
alert(streetadress);
});      
});
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to look at the types property of each element of the array. `administrative_area_level_2` will not always be the second one.

Comment: No...issue is that reverse geocoding is not an exact science and often geocoders can't give the precision you want or as many results as you expect

Comment: Related question: [extract province from location using google api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773036/extract-province-from-location-using-google-api)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract a specific data from the json using python}(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865043/how-to-extract-a-specific-data-from-the-json-using-python)

Comment: woah thanks geocodezip.... my problem solve now