# Selecting a single address from google maps api with multiple results

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the google maps API for a project I am working on that requires the user to input an address such as a town, city or postcode.

I have got the results from google ready for use. The issue I am facing is that if A town appears in multiple places in the country. For example, Ashford (in the UK) his A town based in Middlesex and in Kent.

How could I get a user to select which they meant? I'm confident in generating a select form, but i need a way if possible using PHP functions to get the 2 seperate counties. As you'll see from the snippet, there is no key to separate the two results.

Just a note, I am using PHP.

Here's the results google gives me back:

```
object(stdClass)#5519 (2) {
      ["results"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#5541 (5) {
          ["address_components"]=>
          array(5) {
            [0]=>
            object(stdClass)#5546 (3) {
              ["long_name"]=>
              string(7) "Ashford"
              ["short_name"]=>
              string(7) "Ashford"
              ["types"]=>
              array(2) {
                [0]=>
                string(8) "locality"
                [1]=>
                string(9) "political"
              }
            }
            [1]=>
            object(stdClass)#5545 (3) {
              ["long_name"]=>
              string(7) "Ashford"
              ["short_name"]=>
              string(7) "Ashford"
              ["types"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(11) "postal_town"
              }
            }
            [2]=>
            object(stdClass)#5544 (3) {
              ["long_name"]=>
              string(4) "Kent"
              ["short_name"]=>
              string(4) "Kent"
              ["types"]=>
              array(2) {
                [0]=>
                string(27) "administrative_area_level_2"
                [1]=>
                string(9) "political"
              }
            }
            [3]=>
            object(stdClass)#5543 (3) {
              ["long_name"]=>
              string(7) "England"
              ["short_name"]=>
              string(7) "England"
              ["types"]=>
              array(2) {
                [0]=>
                string(27) "administrative_area_level_1"
                [1]=>
                string(9) "political"
              }
            }
            [4]=>
            object(stdClass)#5542 (3) {
              ["long_name"]=>
              string(14) "United Kingdom"
              ["short_name"]=>
              string(2) "GB"
              ["types"]=>
              array(2) {
                [0]=>
                string(7) "country"
                [1]=>
                string(9) "political"
              }
            }
          }
          ["formatted_address"]=>
          string(11) "Ashford, UK"
          ["geometry"]=>
          object(stdClass)#5537 (4) {
            ["bounds"]=>
            object(stdClass)#5539 (2) {
              ["northeast"]=>
              object(stdClass)#5540 (2) {
                ["lat"]=>
                float(51.1841519)
                ["lng"]=>
                float(0.914884)
              }
              ["southwest"]=>
              object(stdClass)#5538 (2) {
                ["lat"]=>
                float(51.1228136)
                ["lng"]=>
                float(0.8276781)
              }
            }
            ["location"]=>
            object(stdClass)#5536 (2) {
              ["lat"]=>
              float(51.1464659)
              ["lng"]=>
              float(0.875019)
            }
            ["location_type"]=>
            string(11) "APPROXIMATE"
            ["viewport"]=>
            object(stdClass)#5534 (2) {
              ["northeast"]=>
              object(stdClass)#5535 (2) {
                ["lat"]=>
                float(51.1841519)
                ["lng"]=>
                float(0.914884)
              }
              ["southwest"]=>
              object(stdClass)#5533 (2) {
                ["lat"]=>
                float(51.1228136)
                ["lng"]=>
                float(0.8276781)
              }
            }
          }
          ["place_id"]=>
          string(27) "ChIJh_M23CLD3kcRHsaOYTRPDSg"
          ["types"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(8) "locality"
            [1]=>
            string(9) "political"
          }
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#5528 (5) {
          ["address_components"]=>
          array(4) {
            [0]=>
            object(stdClass)#5532 (3) {
              ["long_name"]=>
              string(7) "Ashford"
              ["short_name"]=>
              string(7) "Ashford"
              ["types"]=>
              array(2) {
                [0]=>
                string(8) "locality"
                [1]=>
                string(9) "political"
              }
            }
            [1]=>
            object(stdClass)#5531 (3) {
              ["long_name"]=>
              string(6) "Surrey"
              ["short_name"]=>
              string(6) "Surrey"
              ["types"]=>
              array(2) {
                [0]=>
                string(27) "administrative_area_level_2"
                [1]=>
                string(9) "political"
              }
            }
            [2]=>
            object(stdClass)#5530 (3) {
              ["long_name"]=>
              string(7) "England"
              ["short_name"]=>
              string(7) "England"
              ["types"]=>
              array(2) {
                [0]=>
                string(27) "administrative_area_level_1"
                [1]=>
                string(9) "political"
              }
            }
            [3]=>
            object(stdClass)#5529 (3) {
              ["long_name"]=>
              string(14) "United Kingdom"
              ["short_name"]=>
              string(2) "GB"
              ["types"]=>
              array(2) {
                [0]=>
                string(7) "country"
                [1]=>
                string(9) "political"
              }
            }
          }
          ["formatted_address"]=>
          string(11) "Ashford, UK"
          ["geometry"]=>
          object(stdClass)#5524 (4) {
            ["bounds"]=>
            object(stdClass)#5526 (2) {
              ["northeast"]=>
              object(stdClass)#5527 (2) {
                ["lat"]=>
                float(51.4399966)
                ["lng"]=>
                float(-0.4279375)
              }
              ["southwest"]=>
              object(stdClass)#5525 (2) {
                ["lat"]=>
                float(51.4208625)
                ["lng"]=>
                float(-0.4913756)
              }
            }
            ["location"]=>
            object(stdClass)#5523 (2) {
              ["lat"]=>
              float(51.4274516)
              ["lng"]=>
              float(-0.4552643)
            }
            ["location_type"]=>
            string(11) "APPROXIMATE"
            ["viewport"]=>
            object(stdClass)#5521 (2) {
              ["northeast"]=>
              object(stdClass)#5522 (2) {
                ["lat"]=>
                float(51.4399966)
                ["lng"]=>
                float(-0.4279375)
              }
              ["southwest"]=>
              object(stdClass)#5520 (2) {
                ["lat"]=>
                float(51.4208625)
                ["lng"]=>
                float(-0.4913756)
              }
            }
          }
          ["place_id"]=>
          string(27) "ChIJY_intExxdkgRVdGnlWdcKVw"
          ["types"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(8) "locality"
            [1]=>
            string(9) "political"
          }
        }
      }
      ["status"]=>
      string(2) "OK"
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you'll see from the snippet, there is no key to separate the two results.

I'm missing something: why can't you access (pseudo-code) `["results"]["address_components"][2]["long_name"]`?

That's a key that separates the two results: in one record it's Surrey, and in the other it's Kent.

**UPDATE: WRONG. the  key number differs.**

My bad, but what will actually work is to find all `response.results[0].address_components[i].short_name` where i,b are such that `response.results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_2"`. See [this excellent answer (for a response that is GeoJSON, but can be amended appropriately)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6773743/209219).

*Confession*: the reason I haven't explicitly laid out the way to reference the key in question is that every time I have to parse stuff like that out of a set of results I kludge my way through it, forgetting each time how I did it the last time ("Never commit to memory that which you can look up", said Einstein). If it was XML it would be easier.

There might be two towns in Surrey or Kent that have the same name where it is not possible to distinguish between them based on aspatial data - but that's not the case in the example data.

**Confession II**: When I first answered, I 'keyed' on the `administrative_area_level_2` as the right basis for differentiation, and scanned back to find the relevant node - but only looked at the second record. My bad.

Comment: Because key [2] does not align for both results. One is key 2, the other is key 1.

Comment: True (curse my stupid old eyes)... however you could find the tag that had a child="administrative_area_level_2" - find all `response.results[0].address_components[i].short_name` where `i,b` s.t. `response.results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_2"`. See this answer (for a `response` that is GeoJSON, but can be amended appropriately): http://stackoverflow.com/a/6773743/209219 - updated my answer appropriately

Comment: I was trying to do something like this before with "array_search" but it would only find the key belonging to that entry which of course is [0]. This answer is perfect! Thank you very much! Seriously appreciated.